# changing currency using dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

soo i want to know is there a way to change currency by using a dropdown select button?

> example :
>
> - Rupiah (RP) to Dollar (USD)
>
> already try using if-else and failed do I need to use jquery/javascript?

and I try this but still didn't understand

```
    selector = document.getElementById("currencySelector");
var
    currencyElements = document.getElementsByClassName("currency");
var 
    usdChangeRate = {
      AUD: 1.0490, // 1AUD = 1.0490 USD
      EUR: 1.4407, // 1EUR = 1.4407 USD
      GBP: 1.6424,
      USD: 1.0
    };

selector.onchange = function () {
    var toCurrency = selector.value.toUpperCase();

    for (var i=0,l=currencyElements.length; i<l; ++i) {
        var el = currencyElements[i];
        var fromCurrency = el.getAttribute("data-currencyName").toUpperCase();

      if (fromCurrency in usdChangeRate) {
          var // currency change to usd
              fromCurrencyToUsdAmount = parseFloat(el.innerHTML) * usdChangeRate[fromCurrency];
          var  // change to currency unit selected
              toCurrenyAmount = fromCurrencyToUsdAmount / usdChangeRate[toCurrency];

          el.innerHTML = toCurrenyAmount + "<span>" + toCurrency.toUpperCase() + "</span>";
          el.setAttribute("data-currencyName",toCurrency);
      }
    }
};
```

my drodown :

```
<select name="matauang" class="form-control" onchange = "changecurrency()" id="matauang">
            <option value="null" selected disabled>Choose</option>
            <?php foreach($payment as $pay) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $pay["kurs"]; ?>"><?php echo $pay["kurs"]; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

my table :

```
<table class="table table-fixed table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%;" id="tebal">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Jumlah/Quantity </th>
                        <th scope="col">Unit Price </th>
                        <th scope="col">Sub Total </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    foreach ($query as $kiki) : ?>
                        <tr class="table-row">
                            <td><?php echo $kiki["qty_op"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $kiki["price"]; ?></td>
                            <td class="calc"><?php $total = $kiki["qty_op"]*$kiki["price"]; echo $total; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

if there's any way to change table `Sub Total` value into the dollar? because the format I made is `Rupiah (RP)` and I want to change the currency from `Rp` to `Usd` by choosing from the dropdown. if I have to use `js` please tell me because of im really new to `js`

Comment: I don't see any sql related codes and jquery as well, please edit you tags.

Comment: Instead of PHP code, use example HTML. Then create a [mre].

Comment: hey i already edit the post, thanks for the advice